# Trying to get an object from Firebase in Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get information from an object for a detailview.

I have data stored as:

```
async createRecord() {
    const user = await this.fbauth.authState.pipe(first()).toPromise();
    const record = {};
    record['Name'] = this.roomName;
    record['Number'] = this.roomNumber;
    record['Description'] = this.roomDescription;
    record['User'] = { email: user.email };
    this.crudService.create_NewRoom(record).then(resp => {
      this.roomName = "";
      this.roomNumber = undefined;
      this.roomDescription = "";
      this.roomUser = toString();
      console.log(resp);
      this.router.navigate(['rooms']);
    })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

service.ts

```
read_Room(id) {
    return this.firestore.doc('Rooms/' + id);
  }

create_NewRoom(record) {
    return this.firestore.collection('Rooms').add(record);
  }
```

room.page.ts:

```
roomView(record) {
    const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams:{
        info: this.crudService.read_Room(record)
      }
    }
    this.router.navigate(["roomview"], navigationExtras);
  }
}
```

roomview.page.ts:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { 
      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
          if (params && params.info) {
            this.data = params.info;
          }
          console.log(params);
      });
  }
```

roomview.page.html

```
<ion-card-title>
   {{ data }}
</ion-card-title>
```

and returned I only get:

{info: "[object Object]"}
info: "[object Object]"
**proto**: Object

but I'm hoping to see the data I have in that object, such as Name and Number. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use `@angular/fire`In your read_Room(id) method try to implement something like this that will actually extract something from firestore:

```
read_Room(id) {
  this.firestore.collection('Rooms').doc(id).ref.get().then(r => {
    return r.data();
  });
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data this might be the guide you are looking for.